# how to properly include text files in the right directory when using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

my main python file includes opening a text file which exists in the same directory as the app.py file. i also have the kv file in the same directory. when i run:

```
pyinstaller --onedir main.py
```

and then run the exe file which is generated in the dist folder, I get an error in the console saying that there doesn't exist a file called (my text file name).
I tried adding the text file in the app.spec file:

```
a.datas += [("path/to/text.txt", "text.txt")]
```

but it still wouldnt work ( i would get the same error). what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second part of your tuple should be the directory that you want the file in, not the files name.

```
a.datas += [("path/to/text.txt", ".")]
```